# Is there a way to reorder sections/divs on mobile view?

Tags: shopify

Working on a website built in Shopify. I need to reorder divs in Shopify or more specifically, make the product collections display above other sections when in mobile view.

I tried using jQuery: `$("#paragraph3").insertBefore("#paragraph2");`

But it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use css media queries if you edit your liquid template to render a desktop and mobile layout and switch between them based on screen size

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `flex` functionality that allows you to reorder the elements.

For example you can wrap all of the sections with an element and set that to a `display: flex` and use the `order` attribute for the elements you like to move.

Example:

```
<div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="sectiion-1">
        ...
    </div><!-- /.sectiion-1 -->
    <div class="sectiion-2">
        ...
    </div><!-- /.sectiion-2 -->
    ....
</div><!-- /.section-wrapper -->

.section-wrapper { display: flex; }
.section-wrapper .section-1 { order: 2; }
.section-wrapper .section-2 { order: 1; }
```